# SPF default policy when "all" is missing

Tags: spf, defaults

What is the policy that is applied when "all" is missing from an SPF record? For example as in `v=spf1 a ip4:198.51.100.15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by the [RFC 7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.7), the default behavior is to return a "*neutral*" result, meaning as if `?all` was specified.

The following `v=spf1 a ip4:198.51.100.15` and therefore equivalent to `v=spf1 a ip4:198.51.100.15 ?all`.

> If none of the mechanisms match and there is no "redirect" modifier,
> then the check_host() returns a result of "neutral", just as if "?all"
> were specified as the last directive.  If there is a "redirect"
> modifier, check_host() proceeds as defined in Section 6.1.
>
> It is better to use either a "redirect" modifier or an "all" mechanism
> to explicitly terminate processing.  Although there is an implicit
> "?all" at the end of every record that is not explicitly terminated,
> it aids debugging efforts when it is explicitly provided.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> v=spf1 +mx -all
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> v=spf1 +mx redirect=_spf.example.com
> ```